# Como fazer a injeção de dependência com Koin em um projeto com mais de um modulo

Tags: android, kotlin, injeção-de-dependência, modularização

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com vários módulos: `Domain`, `Data`, `Remote`, `Cache`, etc...

Em cada modulo eu criei um arquivo que faz as injeções de dependência daquele respectivo módulo.

**Ex:** No modulo Domain, criei um arquivo `GetDomainModules` e dentro dele faço as injeções de dependência do modulo `Domain`.

```
val getDomainModules = module {
   factory<GetFilmesRepository> { get() }
   factory<GetFilmesUseCase> { GetFilmesUseCaseImpl(get()) }

   factory<GetSeriesRepository> { get() }
   factory<GetSeriesUseCase> { GetSeriesUseCaseImpl(get()) }
}
```

Dito isso, agora preciso chamar estas variáveis no arquivo `Application`. E é ai que está o meu problema, o arquivo `Application` fica no modulo `App`, e quando tento importar alguma variável de outro modulo, o *Android Studio* simplesmente não importa e o código não compila.

Vale ressaltar que a variável `GetViewModules` é importada normalmente, que está dentro do mesmo modulo `App`. O problema é so com variáveis de outros módulos.

Talvez eu esteja fazendo algo errado e não tenha percebido.

```
// Koin - Injection
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
```

[print do problema no Application do modulo App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqwWC.png)

[print da variável do modulo Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhVJ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver eu acessei o `build.gradle` do modulo `App` (que é o modulo onde vou fazer a injeção) e adicionei a seguinte `implementation` dentro de `dependencies`:

```
    implementation project(path: ':domain')
```

Isso adicionou a dependência do modulo `Domain` no modulo `App`, e consegui importar as variáveis corretamente.

Isso pode ser feito também, acessando File > Project Structure > Selecionando o modulo > Clicando no ícone de + em All dependences.